# Aligning margins correctly in android layout

Tags: android

Given below is the screenshot of my screen which contains a progressbar. As you can see from the screen, the spacing between the left and right of the screens and this progressbar is not equal. It is less towards the right. How can I make this the same as the left with less gap?

Any help is appreciated

Code and screenshot below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLink"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/green_progress_color" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TableRow>
```

**EDIT**

Main Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_layout_installing"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/total_progress" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/total_installed_package_installer"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAbort"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            android:onClick="onAbortClick"
            android:text="@string/abort"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonLaunch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            android:text="@string/install"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_layout_installing" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/installingListview"
        style="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your '@drawable/green_progress_color' doesn't stretch. Try with '@android:drawable/progress_horizontal' to check if this is to your layout or your progress drawable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a `TableRow` just on its own like that, remove it and just have the `LinearLayout`. The `TableRow` is causing the problem. `TableRow` must always be nested within a `TableLayout`(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewContent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLink"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/green_progress_color" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have included my main layout as edit. In that you can see that, I have used a `TableLayout`. In my java code, inside a for loop, I add rows to the table layout - `TableRow convertView = (TableRow) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.installing_adapter, null);` and then add the row to `tablelayout.addView(convertView);`

Comment: @user264953 this seems like a strange use of `TableLayout` - if everything is just in a vertical list (you have no columns) just using a LinearLayout would better. Anyway, can you post again? Don't see your edit.

Comment: @user264953 change your parent `TableLayout` `layout_width` to `match_parent`. Also, as a side note, `TableRow` IS a `LinearLayout` anyway, so you don't need the nested `LinearLayouts` under your `TableRows`

Comment: @user264953 Seriously, it's the `TableLayout` and `TableRow` that's screwing it up. Make your top holder a LinearLayout and then your child views the xml above, it'll work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31490/discussion-between-user264953-and-ken-wolf)

Comment: I changed the table layout to linear layout. still same issue